# Is static google-maps api free?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to write an app which uses google maps (via javascript library like gmaps.js). 
I'll GET the GPS positions from my server and I'll use google maps+js library to draw them on map. 
I don't need to use any api-keys.

Is it free and unlimited or even for commercial usage?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the terms of use and pricing, not coding.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/?_ga=2.4867187.1929070197.1625378788-1964795373.1625378788

Answer (score 1):

```
10.1.2 Restrictions against Commercial Use.

(a) No Fees. You must not charge users or any other third party any fee for the use of the Maps API Implementation, the Service, or the Content, except as permitted under Section 9.1.2 (Exceptions).

(b) No Direct Marketing. You must not print more than 5,000 copies of sales collateral materials containing a screenshot of the Content for purposes of commercial sales lead generation ("Direct Marketing") or incorporate the Content as a core part of printed matter (such as printed maps or guide books) that you redistribute for a fee. You must contact the Google Maps API for Work sales team to obtain a direct license if you desire to do either of the above.
```

Google's [Terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

**EDIT**

https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing Shows you the licencing Agreement too!

**More of the licence:**

```
9.1.1 General Rules.

(a) Free Access (No Fees). Your Maps API Implementation must be generally accessible to users without charge and must not require a fee-based subscription or other fee-based restricted access. This rule applies to Your Content and any other content in your Maps API Implementation, whether Your Content or the other content is in existence now or is added later.

(b) Public Access (No Firewall). Your Maps API implementation must not operate (i) only behind a firewall; or (ii) only on an internal network (except during the development and testing phase); or (iii) in a closed community (for example, through invitation-only access).

9.1.2 Exceptions.

(a) Enterprise Agreement with Google. The rules in Section 9.1.1 (Free Access, Public Access) do not apply if you have entered into a separate written agreement with Google (such as a Google Enterprise agreement) or obtained Google's written permission.

(b) Mobile Applications.
(i) The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile application that is sold for a fee through an online store and is downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store. 

(ii) The rule in Section 9.1.1(b) (Public Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is an Android application that uses the Google Maps Android API. (However, the rule in Section 9.1.1(b) (Public Access) will continue to apply if your Maps API Implementation is an Android application that uses any other Maps APIs, unless the Maps API Implementation qualifies for the exception in Section 9.1.2(a) (Enterprise Agreement with Google).)
```